# How to sort an array of objects w.r.t. key using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

My question might seem ditto duplicate, but I have seen several questions and could not satisfy my quest.

I have a data like this:

```
index value
  1    220
  2    123
  3    11123
  4    440
  5    3400
```

I have saved it into `String[] data= new String[5];` as following:

```
data[0]= 1 + " " + 220;
data[1]= 2 + " " + 123;
...
```

Now what I do is:

```
Arrays.sort(data);
```

What it does is sorting, but w.r.t. 1st column.

**I want this to do it for me w.r.t. 2nd column.**

Is it possible or if I am wrong?

Also I am not sure if this is the right way I have used to save this kind of data?

**How about, if I want to use `int`(s) to save these values, how will everything go?**

i.e. from saving data to get it sorted in formal `Java` style?

**EDIT**: This is a two columns case, where I have said `index` and `value`. I am particularly interested in a case with more than two columns and different data types. Where sorting should be performed w.r.t. the elements of any column specified.

Comment: @pbabcdefp sorting problems are always end up preserving orders. what do you think is unnecessary becomes important.

Comment: @Tod give you plus cuz you explain what you did and what you want very well.

Comment: No idea, who hit minus and why?!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a class to hold your two related data elements (index and value) as fields (presumably with getters and setters). Write two Comparator classes, one that sorts by index and one that sorts by value. I would probably create factory methods in the class to get these Comparators.

Rather than create an array of String, you would create an array of your new class. Construct your class instances and assign to the array.

Than you can use `Arrays.sort` on your array with whichever Comparator is appropriate to efficiently sort the array. This also allows you easy access to the individual fields.

Bro - here is some code to get you started...

```
public class Bro {
    private int index;
    private int value;
    public Bro (int index, int value) {
        this.index = index;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public static Comparator<Bro> getIndexComparator() {
        return new Comparator<Bro>() {
            public int compare(Bro o1, Bro o2) {
                return o1.index - o2.index;
            }
        }
    }
}
Bro[] bros = new Bro[5];
bros[0] = new Bro(1, 220);
...
Arrays.sort(bros, Bro.getIndexComparator());
```

Java provides two similar interfaces: Comparator and Comparable. If a class has a natural sort order, you would implement Comparable. If you need to sort a class in more than one way, you will implement a Comparator for each sort order that you need.

Comment: if you explain comparator vs comparable and why the op should use comparator I gladly vote u up. if you like you can see **parallel sort in Java 8**

Comment: @KickButtowski Comparable doesn't seem relevant to the question, but I added a couple sentences to explain why.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a Tuple class to hold your key/values and then use a comparator to
sort based on keys/values. Something like the following. It's written using Java 8.

```
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tuple[] data = new Tuple[5];
    data[0] = new Tuple(1, 220);
    data[1] = new Tuple(2, 123);
    data[2] = new Tuple(3, 11123);
    data[3] = new Tuple(4, 440);
    data[4] = new Tuple(5, 3400);

    Arrays.sort(data, (t1, t2) -> t1.value - t2.value);
   }
}


class Tuple {
   int key;
   int value;

   public Tuple(int key, int value) {
     this.key = key;
     this.value = value;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
    return "(" + key + ", " + value + ")";
   }
}
```

About the general case, I'm afraid in Java you cannot define a type with unknown number of generic types. But if you know beforehand how many columns yo have, you can do the following:

```
class Tuple<T1 extends Comparable<T1>, T2 extends Comparable<T2>, ..., Tn extends Comparable<Tn>> {
   T1 col_1;
   T2 col_2;
   ...
   Tn col_n;

   public Tuple(T1 col_1, T1 col_2, ..., Tn col_n) {
     this.col_1 = col_1;
     this.col_2 = col_2;
     ...
     this.col_n = col_n;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
    return "(" + col_1 + ", " + ... +  col_n + ")";
   }
}
```

And then sort based on the column number as follows:

```
Arrays.sort(data, (t1, t2) -> t.col_i.compareTo(t2.col_i))
```

So essentially, each column type knows how to compare itself with its own type.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a `Map` for this kind of data. With `index` as key and `value` as the data associated with the key.

Or the the other way round if you want to sort using `value` mostly.

Something like:

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> dataMap = new TreeMap<>(); //sorts the entries according to key
dataMap.add(220, 1);
dataMap.add(123, 2);
...
```

You can further lookup bunch of methods to iterate over TreeMap [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Comment: I could not figure out how to use these, what you have suggest, though I have gone through these. It would be nice if you provide it with a solution.

Comment: Map is not an ordered Collection, so it is not a natural fit for anything that requires sorting.

Comment: @rob this instance is different than a contract.

Comment: if I do not make mistake, linkedhashmap is ordered am I right?

Comment: @KickButtowski LinkedHashMap provides a consistent order (often insertion order), but does not give control of the order. Plus, the answer says "Map" not "LinkedHashMap".

Comment: @rob give you plus but map is interface as far as I know ?!!

Comment: @KickButtowski Map indeed is an interface. My point was that as soon as you start talking about a specific interface, you only have the methods of that interface available to you. The more important problem with this answer is the fact that a Map doesn't provide the ability to sort, let alone sort in multiple different ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom comparator to re-split the strings only during the comparisons, and compare using the int values. So instead of using

```
Arrays.sort(data);
```

You should use:

```
Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            int val1 = Integer.valueOf(o1.split(" ")[1]);
            int val2 = Integer.valueOf(o2.split(" ")[1]);
            // Ascending
            if (val1 > val2) {
                return 1;
            } else if (val1 == val2) {
                return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        }    
});
```

Comment: Quite true that if you concatenate the various attributes using a delimiter that you can parse to get the original attributes. However, if you ever would need to do that, you are much better off never concatenating in the first place. Why spend the time (and garbage) to go back and forth via String when it would be easier and more clear to just store the data elements separately in fields of an object?

Comment: No argument there :) My answer relates to the question "as is". Assuming that @tod saves the data as mentioned in the question, then this is the quickest and cleanest way to solve it. No doubt there are better ways to save related data elements, but that's assuming that you have no other constraints.

Comment: Just saw the edit in @tod 's question, so a more general solution would be of course more appropriate

Comment: @dcoder check my answer with generic types. Is it what you want with a general solution? The thing is that for my solution, the number of columns should be known at compile time.

Comment: @Ali, what I meant was that it should be explained that the proper Java "way" to do it would be probably be by using an object which stores these values, and not by concatenating them to a string. Your initial example is a good one (though I personally wouldn't call a key-value pair a tuple).